# Open an URL and click a button on the newly loaded page

Tags: javascript, html

I am just starting to learn Javascript and I want to write a script that redirects to another URL, and after the URL has been loaded , it click on a "Next button and so on.

I am using the following script, which it is executed after a button press in the first html page:

```
function GoToURLAndClickNext() {  
  var w = window.open("file:///C:/test_click.html");
  w.document.getElementById('button id').click();
}
```

test_click.html
looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Test button</h1>

<p>Test </p>

<button type="button" id="button id" onclick="alert('click event occured')">Click here</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately the script does not work... It opens correctly the "test_click.html" document, but it does not automatically click on the "button id".
Is it possible to implement such behaviour? Ideally I would like to navigate over mutliple html pages in a tree-fashion way.
Thanks
z

Comment: To the user that edited this and those that approved the edit: stack snippet is for **running** code only. Rollback to the original.

Comment: jsfiddle please....

Comment: I doubt that it can be done like this; my approach would be to add `mybutton.click()` on `window.onload()` event in your new opened page

Comment: Well, this is exactly my problem ... I don't want to/ can't add new functionality in the new opened page. I am trying to understand if this can be done from a script that is solely executed from the first page.